# Ignore driver: cloudstor:aws in docker-compose.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I'd like the following `driver` and `driver_opts` to be ignored when running in a particular environment (mainly development):

```
volumes:
  foobar:
    name: '{{.Service.Name}}-{{.Task.Slot}}-foobar-vol'
    # AWS EBS only
    driver: cloudstor:aws
    driver_opts:
      backing: relocatable
      ebstype: gp2
      size: 4
```

If I run `docker-compose up` using the same `docker-compose.yml` file in my local dev environment, I get the following message:

```
ERROR: Volume {{.Service.Name}}-{{.Task.Slot}}-foobar-vol specifies nonexistent driver cloudstor:aws
```

I can override this locally if I redeclare the named volume `foobar` in `docker-compose.override.yml`, but I'd also like to build and run the production environment locally without needing to create a new compose file.